# Hypercube sides

Tags: code-golf, geometry, combinatorics

Your goal is to output all the "sides" (corners, edges, faces, etc.) of an N-dimensional unit hypercube, where N is non-negative. A "side" is defined as any (N-M)-dimension surface embedded in N-dimensional space, where `1 <= M <= N`.

The hypercube spans the space [0, 1] in each dimension. For example, for N=2 the square is bounded by the corner points (0, 0) and (1, 1).

## Input

Your function/program should take a single non-negative integer N. You may assume N <= 10.

## Outputs

The output may be to any convenient format desired: return a list, print to stdio/file, output parameters, etc.

The output must contain the min/max bounds of all unique sides. Order does not matter.

**Example sides formats**

A 0D side (a.k.a. a point) in 3D space could be bounded by:

```
# in [(min0, max0),...] format, this is the point 0,1,0
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
```

A 1D side (a.k.a. an edge) in 2D space could be bounded by:

```
# in [(min0, min1,...), (max0, max1,...)] format, this is the line from point (0,0) to (1,0)
[(0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

Note that it is ok to flatten the output any way you want ([min0, max0, min1, max1, ...] or [min0, min1, min2, ..., max0, max1, max2, ...], etc.)

[Wikipedia has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube) of the number of sides to expect for various hypercubes. In total, there should be `3N-1` results.

**Full sample outputs**

This uses the convention `[min0, max0, min1, max1, ...]`

N = 0

```
empty list (or no output)
```

N = 1

```
[0, 0]
[1, 1]
```

N = 2

```
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

N = 3

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

## Scoring

This is code golf; shortest code wins. Standard loop-holes apply. You may use built-in functions like "permute a sequence" so long as it wasn't designed specifically for this problem.

Your code should run in a reasonable amount of time for N <= 6 (say, 10 minutes or less)

Comment: Please, someone make something visual. That's what hypercubes are for

Comment: you said `but you may use`. Did you mean `you may use` or `you may not use`?

Comment: functions like permute/cartesian product are allowed.

Answer (score 5):

### Pyth, 10 chars

```
P^cj49J2JQ
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=P%5Ecj49J2JQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A2%0A3&debug=1) Output is a list of sides each in the format. `[[min0, max0],[min1, max1],...]`.

```
P             All but the last element of 
 ^       Q     the nth cartesian power of
   j49J2        the number 49 as a binary list [1,1,0,0,0,1]
  c     J         split into chunks of 2 [[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]]
```

In our output, we want all lists of `n` elements from `[[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]]`, except the one with only `[0,1]`'s. This is just the `n`th cartesian power of `[[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]]` with the last element removed.

The list `[[1,1],[0,0],[0,1]]` is created by converting 49 into binary and breaking into chunks of 2.  One can do `.CU2 2` to get `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]` as all sorted sublists of 2 elements from `[0,1]`, but we need `[0,1]` at the start or end to remove the list with only it from the product.

Answer (score 4):

### CJam (13 bytes)

```
49Yb2/rim*);`
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=49Yb2%2Frim*)%3B%60&input=3)

Output format is as a list of list of ranges: e.g. for input `1` (where the two sides are the points `(0, 0)` and `(1, 1)`) the output is `[[[1 1]] [[0 0]]]`.

#### Dissection

```
49Yb2/   e# Generate the list of ranges: [[1 1] [0 0] [0 1]]
rim*     e# Take the nth Cartesian power
);       e# Remove the last one, which is the full hypercube
`        e# Format for output
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>66</s> 63

Returns an array of strings, each one containing 2n `0`s and `1`s without separators.

```
->n{(0..3**n-2).map{|i|s=""
n.times{s+="0011"[-i%3,2];i/=3}
s}}
```

In a similar way to at at least one other answer it generates all possibilities of `["00","11","01"]` repeated n times, except `"0101....0101"`, by iterating through all the n-digit base 3 numbers `00..00` to `22..21` (deliberately missing `22..22`) and then substituting. Initially I had the string `"011101"` (`"01"` had to be at the end) but then I realised if I fed `-i` instead of `i` to the `%3` operation, I could swap the 2 and 1. I was then able to reduce the string to `"0011"`, overlapping the three possible 2-character strings I required.

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
f=->n{
  (0..3**n-2).map{|i|            #iterate through all n-digit base 3 numbers 00..00 to 22..21
    s=""
    n.times{                     #for each base 3 digit in i append the following to s
      s+="0011"[-i%3,2]          #0 --> 0 -->"00";   -1 --> 2 --> "11";   -2 --> 1 --> "01"
      i/=3                       #divide by 3 to remove the last base 3 digit from i
    }
    s                            #add s to the array being built by map.
  }
}

puts f[gets.to_i]
```

**Output n=2**

```
0000
1100
0100
0011
1111
0111
0001
1101
```

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 24 bytes

```
2ri2*m*{2/__:$=\2,a-*},p
```

Uses the same interleaved `[min0 max0 min1 max1 ...]` format as the test cases in the challenge. It solves `N = 10` in a couple of minutes.

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=2ri2*m*%7B2%2F__%3A%24%3D%5C2%2Ca-*%7D%2Cp&input=5)

#### Explanation

```
2      e# Push a 2.
ri     e# Read input and convert to integer N.
2*     e# Multiply by 2.
m*     e# Get all 2N-tuples consisting of 0 and 1 as potential sides. A tuple is a valid
       e# side if a) all of its min/max pairs are sorted and b) not all of them are [0 1],
       e# because that corresponds to the entire N-dimensional hypercube.
{      e# Filter the tuples...
  2/   e#   Split the tuple into min/max pairs.
  __   e#   Make two copies.
  :$   e#   Sort each pair in the second copy.
  =    e#   Check for equality with the first copy.
  \    e#   Swap with the original list of pairs.
  2,a- e#   Remove all [0 1].
  *    e#   Repeat this array 0 or 1 times depending on the first result. This effectively
       e#   computes the logical AND of two truthy/falsy values.
},
p      e# Pretty-print the list of sides.
```

Answer (score 0):

### ES7, 88 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(3**n-1)].map((_,i)=>[...(3**n+i).toString(3).slice(1)].map(x=>[x%2,+!!x]))
```

Turns out I ended up porting the Ruby solution, except I return a list of an array of a pair of bounds for each dimension, since that makes for the shortest code.